# how to import data from mysql to Apache Hadoop HDFS installation.

Tags: mysql, import, hadoop

How to import data from mysql to HDFS. I can't use sqoop as it's a HDFS installation not cloudera. I used below link to setup HDFS. My hadoop version is 0.20.2
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you using Sqoop as it's not in any way tied to Cloudera specific software.

Comment: Can you please guide me as in how to configure Sqoop?

Comment: I was able to do it by installing HIVE and than importing txt files into HDFS using HIVE. .. thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from sqoop, you could try [hiho](https://github.com/sonalgoyal/hiho). I have heard good things about it. (Never used it though)

But mostly what I have seen is people end up writing their own flows to do this. If hiho doesn;t work out, you can dump data from MySql using [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html). Then load into HDFS using a map-reduce job or Pig/Hive.

I have heard Sqoop is pretty good and is widely used (This is hearsay again, I have never used it myself). Now that [it is an apache incubator project](http://sqoop.apache.org/index.html), I think it might have started supporting apache releases of hadoop, or at least might have made it less painful for non-cloudera versions. [The doc](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_releases) does say that it support Apache hadoop v0.21. Try to make it work with your hadoop version. It might not be that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question, but if you want to use the database as input to a Map Reduce job, and don't want to copy to HDFS, you could use the DBInputFormat to input directly from the database.